# On scrolling showing intervesion error in chrome console

Tags: infinite-scroll

When I scroll the page in chrome it show the intervention error.
I tried adding various script like

```
window.addEventListener("mousedown,wheel", handleMouseDown, { passive: false});
```

but unable to fix that.
Please see screenshot attached.

[image]

Comment: What is `handleMouseDown`?

Comment: Basically this is the callback function but have you any idea how to fix this issue.

Comment: I know that. _What’s the code?_

Answer (score 0):

I got an answer as google chrome has updated the feature of preventDefault on javascript. So if you delete this (preventDefault ) from js library then error generating would be removed.